# Quesiton about uniform convergence at the origin

Tags: real-analysis

We have a function $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{1/(2n-1)}$$

Looks like for any value of $x$ as $n$ goes $\to\infty$, $f(x)\to 1$. But from what we can see about $f(x)$, what do we know about uniform convergence on sets containing the origin? I'm assuming it has to do with some discontinuities either in $f_n$ or $f$ near the origin, but I can't seem to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n\to f$ uniformly on an open set $U$ containing $0$, since every $f_n$ is continuous at $0$, $f$ must be continuous at $0$. In the present case, $f(x)=1$ for every $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$ hence $f$ is not continuous at zero and the convergence $f_n\to f$ cannot be uniform on $U$.

Comment: thanks for the response! :)